# Prevent Method from being Trimmed

Tags: c#, .net, linker

I'm trying to prevent IL Linker from trimming a method in my .NET WebAssembly.  Because the method Callback() is called externally, the static analysis believes it is not used and removes it.  There's a few attributes I've tried, DynamicDependency, DynamicallyAccessedMembers, and RequiresUnreferencedCode, but I have a feeling I'm not using them correctly.

I'm aware I can prevent trimming with XML config or by doing something like `if(someAlwaysFalseCondition) { Callback(); }` but those aren't feasible solutions in my context.

How should I apply an attribute to Callback() to prevent it from being trimmed by the IL Linker?

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded.");
    }
    
    public static void Callback()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callback");
    }
}
```

Comment: By "xml config" do you mean `<BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>` in the project file or [using another config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/configure-linker?view=aspnetcore-3.1#control-linking-with-a-configuration-file)?

Comment: Either. I wouldn't want to completely disable the linker, but I also don't want downstream projects consuming this assembly to need to add XML configs.   Hence why I'd like to solve it declaratively with attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute is applied to methods, and specifies which other types, methods or members should be included. In this example its "Main()":

```
public class Program
{
    [DynamicDependency(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.All, typeof(Program))]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded.");
    }

    public static void Callback()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callback");
    }
}
```