# NET8 NativeAOT: Type.GetProperties() doesn't work for some types but does for others! why?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-8.0, getproperties, native-aot

I have a program which was successfully published with NET8 NativeAOT, but Type.GetProperties() works for some class where properties r returned properly, but not for others, where it returns no property at all. i don't know why nor find a clue to debug. Can someone give some hints?

it doesn't work for a simple class like :

```
    public sealed partial class UILogText(string name = "", string text = "") 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = name;
        public string Text { get; set; } = text;

        public override string ToString() => Text;
    }
```

but works well for some complicated class like :

```
 public sealed partial class GatewayInfo : GatewayEntry, IEntryInfo 
    { 
       //39 public properties (note:not fields) ...
    }
```

I know nothing more can i do with it.

I know NativeAOT has problems with reflections in some cases, but the problem here is that it already worked for some classes. I can't tell the key difference between above mentioned exmaples.

Can someone give a hint on what's happening here? or any clue to find out?

Comment: Just a guess here, but it may be that all the calls to the `Name` and `Text` properties were inlined, and then the properties themselves were [trimmed away](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options) because they were not called.    Try disabling trimming and see if the problem resolves.  Or see [Prevent Method from being Trimmed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71268097) to disable trimming more selectively.

Comment: Ur guess is right! thx!! i adopted the solution u provided - solved! despite it's nothing to do with the inlining.  ps. nativeaot trims by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[method: DynamicDependency(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicProperties, typeof(UILogText))]
    public sealed partial class UILogText(string name = "", string text = "") 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = name;
        public string Text { get; set; } = text;

        public override string ToString() => Text;
    }
```

According to comment above, add DynamicDependencyAttribute solved my problem!